# Is there a durable store for deb files (like a maven repo?)

Tags: maven, repository, debian, deb

I have a maven built docker image that was dependent on [libssl1.0.2_1.0.2d-3_amd64.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2d-3_amd64.deb), but this has now a 404 and has been replaced by [libssl1.0.2_1.0.2e-1_amd64.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2e-1_amd64.deb).

This is a problem because maven builds are meant to be durable - ie you can rebuild them at any point in the future.   The main maven repo is durable, so artefacts taken from that will be there in the future.     I could move the debs I need into the maven repo, but that is a bit of abuse of other peoples storage...

So is there a durable store of debian files that is guaranteed to exist... well at least until the revolution/meteor strike/Jurassic resurrection etc.

Comment: You need to create a separate docker image which contains the files you need so you reference the one you have created...Apart from that i don't understand why a Maven build depends on a deb package?

Comment: The maven build is creating a docker image, so it needs to install deb packages to prepare the image.  Sure I can create a base docker image (and we do), but that just moves the problem to the build that makes the base image... plus we now need a durable store for docker images!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this yourself with free, open-source tools. You can create your own [APT repository](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-reprepro-for-a-secure-package-repository-on-ubuntu-14-04) for storing Debian packages. If you are interested in using GPG signature to sign repository metadata [read this](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/).

Once you've created the repository, you can create a configuration file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` pointing to your repository. You can run `apt-get update` to refresh your systems apt cache, and then run `apt-get install` to install the package of your choice.

BTW, you can install a particular version of a package by running: `apt-get install packagename=version`.

For example, to install version 1.0 of "test", run: `apt-get install test=1.0`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with any of this yourself you can just use [packagecloud.io](https://packagecloud.io) for hosting Debian, RPM, RubyGem, and Python PyPI repositories. A lot of people who use our service have your exact use case, where Debian packages they depend on disappear from public repositories so they upload them to us.

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these is durable in the sense that maven repos are.  An internal APT repository is not good for an open source project that will used by others and may outlive the organisation that created it.  Ditto for packagecloud.io, if the organisation that creates the project ceases to be, then the bills don't get paid and the artefact vanishes and the project no longer builds.

Comment: we offer free plans for open source projects, so there'd be no bill to be paid. but other than that there are no other options. the common repos that are generated by ubuntu or debian don't persist older versions of software, so there isn't much you can do.